# Oracle does not start on system startup

Tags: linux, oracle, startup, configuration-files

I need to configure oracle database of a remote server to start in system startup.
I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wP6gNT1FfeQ) that is almost the same as others.
I am not allowed to restart the server, only can suggest the owner to do something on server.

The server configurations are similar to what the tutorial say but oracle database does not start at system startup. This is the /etc/dbora and /etc/init.d/oratab file contents:

dbora:

```
#!/bin/sh
# chkconfig: 345 99 10
# description: Oracle auto start-stop script.
#
# Set ORA_HOME to be equivalent to the $ORACLE_HOME
# from which you wish to execute dbstart and dbshut;
#
# Set ORA_OWNER to the user id of the owner of the
# Oracle database in ORA_HOME.

ORA_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1
ORA_OWNER=oracle

if [ ! -f $ORA_HOME/bin/dbstart ]
then
    echo "Oracle startup: cannot start"
    exit
fi

case "$1" in
    'start')
        su $ORA_OWNER -c "$ORA_HOME/bin/lsnrctl start" &
        su $ORA_OWNER -c $ORA_HOME/bin/dbstart &
        touch /var/lock/subsys/dbora
        ;;
    'stop')
        su $ORA_OWNER -c $ORA_HOME/bin/dbshut
        su $ORA_OWNER -c "$ORA_HOME/bin/lsnrctl stop"
        rm -f /var/lock/subsys/dbora
        ;;
esac
```

oratab:

```
    # This file is used by ORACLE utilities.  It is created by root.sh
    # and updated by the Database Configuration Assistant when creating
    # a database.

        # A colon, ':', is used as the field terminator.  A new line terminates
        # the entry.  Lines beginning with a pound sign, '#', are comments.
        #
        # Entries are of the form:
        #   $ORACLE_SID:$ORACLE_HOME:<N|Y>:
        #


 # The first and second fields are the system identifier and home
    # directory of the database respectively.  The third filed indicates
    # to the dbstart utility that the database should , "Y", or should not,
    # "N", be brought up at system boot time.
    #
    # Multiple entries with the same $ORACLE_SID are not allowed.
    #
    #
    orcl:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1:Y
    orcl:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1:N
```

What is wrong with these files?

Comment: depending on the server OS you should do someting like chkconfig --add oracle (for centos / redhat / fedora) . Please let me know the server OS

Comment: @NoelCarcases The server is Oracle Linux

Comment: The same... chkconfig --add oracle or chkconfig --level 2345 oracle on. Let me know if it works

Comment: @NoelCarcases look at the last line of oratab, please. Is that the problem?

Comment: did not notice that ... I think you should remove     

orcl:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1:N //this line

Answer (score 1):

leave only first row

```
**# Multiple entries with the same $ORACLE_SID are not allowed.**
#
#
orcl:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1:Y
```